# How to show debug logs using java.util.logging

Tags: java, debugging, logging, java.util.logging

I've been asked to replace log4j with java.util.logging but i have a problem in replacing the debug logs.

In log4j when you want to show logs only in debug mode you just have to write:

log.debug("msg");

I can't find the equivalent method in java.util.logging. Can someone help me?

I tried setting the different Levels of the log, but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use log levels in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817738/how-to-use-log-levels-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

JUL doesn't have DEBUG and TRACE levels, it has CONFIG, FINE, FINER and FINEST. You'll have to decide which ones to use.

You'll also have to replace ERROR with SEVERE.